# Как получить и вывести имена всех таблиц?

Tags: mysql

До сих пор не приходилось что-то делать с таблицами БД, не зная их имён. И теперь возникла необходимость занести в массив имена большого числа таблиц, чтобы их перебрать.

Как получить имена всех таблиц?

Comment: `SHOW TABLES FROM db_name;` db_name -- название вашей БД

Comment: [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/tables-table.html)